# How to call functions from one subclass to another subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclass, invoke, subclassing

```
class Acct:
    def __init__(self, deposit):
        self.balance = deposit
    def balance(self):
        print("Your balance is $",self.balance)
    def getDeposit(self, deposit):
        self.balance = self.balance + deposit
        print("Your new balance is $",self.balance)
    def getWithdraw(self, withdraw):
        self.balance = self.balance - withdraw
        print("Your new balance is $",self.balance)

class ChkAcct(Acct):
    def __init__(self, deposit):
        super().__init__(deposit)

class SavAcct(Acct):
    def __init__(self, deposit):
        super().__init__(deposit)

savings_account_starting_balance = float(input("Enter a starting balance for your savings account :"))
savings_account = SavAcct(savings_account_starting_balance)
savings_account.balance()       

checking_account_starting_balance = float(input("Enter a starting balance for your checking account :"))
checking_account = ChkAcct(checking_account_starting_balance)
checking_account.balance()

savings_account.getDeposit(float(input("Enter a deposit ammout for savings account :")))

checking_account.getDeposit(float(input("Enter a deposit ammout for checking account:")))

savings_account.getWithdraw(float(input("Enter a withdraw ammout from savings:")))

checking_account.getWithdraw(float(input("Enter a withdraw ammout from checking:")))
```

I need to make 2 classes `ChkAcct` and `SavAcct`. Each class should have a `balance` property. Each class should have a `deposit` method. Each class should have a `withdraw` method. Each class should also have a `transfer` method that calls its own withdraw method and invokes the `deposit` method from the other class.

I can't seem to figure out how to make the transfer methods.

Comment: If you want to take money from one account and put it another, you should do it with *instances*. For example, `checking_acount.deposit(savings_account.withdraw(amount))`. It doesn't really make sense to have a method that targets a particular other class.

Comment: Give the method an instance of the other class, and invoke the withdraw/deposit method on it.

Comment: As @Carcigenicate suggests you'd then have e.g. `checking_account.transfer(amount, savings_account)`. This means the subclasses don't have to know much about each other, just that they both share the `Acct` interface.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement this.
Here's one:

```
class Acct:
    def __init__(self, deposit):
        self.balance = deposit

    # Try to avoid same names for methods and properties, unless you have a good reason for it
    # Otherwise you may end up with an error like this: "TypeError: 'float' object is not callable",
    # when you try to call your original balance() method
    # So I renamed it to getBalance()
    def getBalance(self):
        print("Your balance is $",self.balance)

    def getDeposit(self, deposit):
        self.balance = self.balance + deposit
        print("Your new balance is $",self.balance)

    def getWithdraw(self, withdraw):
        self.balance = self.balance - withdraw
        print("Your new balance is $",self.balance)

    # Transfer 'amount' from current instance to 'destination' instance
    def transfer(self, amount, destination):
        self.getWithdraw(amount)
        destination.getDeposit(amount)

class ChkAcct(Acct):
    def __init__(self, deposit):
        super().__init__(deposit)


class SavAcct(Acct):
    def __init__(self, deposit):
        super().__init__(deposit)


# Set up the accounts and fund them
print("1. Setting accounts")
savings_account = SavAcct(100.00)
checking_account = ChkAcct(200.00)

savings_account.getBalance()
checking_account.getBalance()

# Now do the transfer
print("2. Transferring money")
savings_account.transfer(50.00, checking_account)
```

The output will be this:

```
# 1. Setting accounts
# Your balance is $ 100.0
# Your balance is $ 200.0
# 2. Transferring money
# Your new balance is $ 50.0
# Your new balance is $ 250.0
```

The other way is to have a standalone function for this:

```
def transfer(amount, origin, destination):
    origin.getWithdraw(amount)
    destination.getDeposit(amount)
```

And then call it:

```
transfer(50.00, savings_account, checking_account)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Acct:
    def __init__(self, deposit):
        self.balance = deposit
    def getBalance(self):
        print("Your new "+str(self.__class__.__name__)+" balance is $",self.balance)
    def getDeposit(self, deposit):
        self.balance = self.balance + deposit
        print("Your new "+str(self.__class__.__name__)+" balance is $",self.balance)
    def getWithdraw(self, withdraw):
        self.balance = self.balance - withdraw
        print("Your new "+str(self.__class__.__name__)+" balance is $",self.balance)
    def getTransfer (self, account, destination):
        self.getWithdraw(account)
        destination.getDeposit(account)

class ChkAcct(Acct):
    def __init__(self, deposit):
        super().__init__(deposit)

class SavAcct(Acct):
    def __init__(self, deposit):
        super().__init__(deposit)

savings_account_starting_balance = float(input("Enter a starting balance for your savings account :"))
new_savings_account = SavAcct(savings_account_starting_balance)
new_savings_account. getBalance()
checking_account_starting_balance = float(input("Enter a starting balance for your checking account :"))
new_checking_account = ChkAcct(checking_account_starting_balance)
new_checking_account. getBalance()
new_savings_account.getDeposit(float(input("Enter a deposit ammout for savings account :")))
new_checking_account.getDeposit(float(input("Enter a deposit ammout for checking account :")))
new_savings_account.getWithdraw(float(input("Enter a withdraw ammout from savings :")))
new_checking_account.getWithdraw(float(input("Enter a withdraw ammout from checking :")))
new_checking_account.getTransfer(float(input("Enter a transfer ammount from checking to savings :")),new_savings_account)
new_savings_account.getTransfer(float(input("Enter a transfer ammount from savings to checking :")),new_checking_account)
```

thanks to a friend I ended up with this. I like the added touch of calling back the class name in the output to help the user differentiate account balance